# The coefficient and asymptotic in generating function

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, generating-functions, analyticity, legendre-polynomials

> Let $L_n$ be the set of all the paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,0)$ such that every step is $u=(1,1)$ , $d=(1,-1)$ and $r=(2,0)$.
> Notice that the path could go under the $x$ axis.
>
> **a.** Write a generating function of the number of paths in $L_n$.
>
> **b.** Analyze the asymptotic of $|L_n|$ for a large n.

*My trial:*
in part a, I wrote:

Every path = (empty path) or (r every path) or (u Schröder path d every path) or (d Schröder path u every path).

Now, denote our g.f. by $A(x)$ and Schröder g.f. by $S(x)$, and denote $x$ to count half of the length, get: $A(x)=1+xA(x)+xS(x)A(x)+xS(x)A(x)$. Thus,

$$A(x)=\frac{1}{1-x-2xS(x)}$$

Then if we substitute the formula of $S(x)=\frac{1-x-\sqrt {(1-x)^2-4x}}{2x}$ :

$$A(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt {(1-x)^2-4x}}$$

In part b, to analyze the asymptotic of $|L_n|$, I guess I should find the coeifficient of $[x^n]$ in $A(x)$ where $A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} |L_n| x^{2n}$.
However if we solve denominator of $A(x) = 0$ we get

\begin{align*}
(1-x)^2-4x=0
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
x^2-6x+1=0
\end{align*}

so, $x=3 \pm 2\sqrt2$. So the g.f. will be analytic if we delete the intervals $(3+\sqrt2, \infty)$ and $(-\infty,3-\sqrt2)$.
Write:
$A(x)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{(x- r_1)(x-r_2)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-r_1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-r_2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x/r_1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x/r_2}}$ where $r_1=3+\sqrt{8}$ and $r_2=3-\sqrt{8}$.
Then, $A(x)=(\sum_{n\geq 0}  (1/r_1)^n x^n \sum_{n\geq 0} (1/r_2)^n x^n)^{1/2}= \sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n} (1/r_1)^j (1/r_3)^{n-j} x^n$ ,
here I used Caushy formula.

So, $[x^n] A(x)= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (1/r_1)^j (1/r_2)^{n-j}$

$L_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n} (r_2/r_1)^j (1/r_2)^n$.
But this was not much useful!

*Edited*:
Another approach, which does not use the Legendre polynomial:

*I found in *oeis* the sequence of this problem is A001850 and it shows that the coefficient of the series is $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}{n+k \choose k}$ .In addition,  wikipedia page : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number, mentioned the coefficient and the asymptotic of the above  g.f : $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}$  which is the g.f of the  Delannoy number, but without explanation/proof.
How they find the coefficient of this generating function, and how they analayzed its asymptotic then?

Many thanks!

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/379065/11260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show the following asymptotic expansion of $A(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}$ is valid:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^n]A(x)\sim\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{n}\right)^n}{2\sqrt{\left(3\sqrt{2}-4\right)\pi n}}
\left(1-\frac{8-3\sqrt{2}}{32n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
$A(x)$ has the isolated singularities
\begin{align*}x_0=3-2\sqrt{2}\qquad x_1=3+2\sqrt{2}, \qquad x_0x_1=1
\end{align*}
with $x_0$ being the dominant singularity determining the asymptotic expansion (1).

**Expansion at $x_0=3-2\sqrt{2}$:**

At first we consider
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x-x_0\right)\left(x-x_1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0x_1}}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{x}{x_0}\right)}}\,\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{x}{x_1}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)x}}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

We expand (with some help of Wolfram Alpha) the first term in (2) at $x_0$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)x}}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}+\frac{1}{16\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}\left(x-\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\\
&\qquad+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(x-\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}-\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{16\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)\\
&\qquad+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)^2\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

The other term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x}}$ in (2) is already in the expanded form we need.

**Asymptotic expansion:**

We follow chapter VI in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick and get from Theorem VI.1 an asymptotic expansion of
\begin{align*}
[x^n]f(x)=(1-x)^{-\alpha}\qquad\qquad\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
We take terms up to order $2$ and get
\begin{align*}
[x^n]f(x)\sim\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\left(1+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\tag{5}
\end{align*}
We need from (5) the following expansions
\begin{align*}
[x^n](1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}&\sim\frac{n^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}
\left(1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\left(1-\frac{1}{8n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\tag{6}\\
[x^n](1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}&\sim\frac{n^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}
\left(1+\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^3\pi}}\left(1+\frac{3}{8n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\tag{7}
\end{align*}

Note, that (4) is given in *standard form*, but we have something like $(1-x_1x)^{-\alpha}$ instead. We overcome this by recalling a Taylor series expansion and noting that
\begin{align*}
[x^n]f(x)&=x_{1}^{-n}[x^n]f\left(x_1x\right)\\
[x^n]f(x_1x)&=x_1^n[x^n]f(x)\\
&=\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^n[x^n]f(x)\tag{8}
\end{align*}

**Putting all together:**

We take from (3) the expansion at $x_0$ and get
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)x}}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x}}\\
&=\Bigg\{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}-\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{16\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)^2\right)\Bigg\}\,\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\qquad-\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{16\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(1-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x\right)^\frac{3}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Using (6) and (7) together with (8) we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^n]A(x)}&\color{blue}{\sim}\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\left(1-\frac{1}{8n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^n\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)}{32\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2\sqrt{\left(3\sqrt{2}-4\right)\pi n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{8n}
+\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{16\sqrt{2}n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)\\
&\,\,=\color{blue}{\frac{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2\sqrt{\left(3\sqrt{2}-4\right)\pi n}}\left(1
-\frac{8-3\sqrt{2}}{32n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 }\right)\right)}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

*Note:* The expansion (1) can be found e.g. in *[Asymptotics of the weighted Delannoy numbers](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Ernoble/papers/weighteddelannoy5.pdf)* by R. Noble.

Comment: 4 hours ago

Hi @Markus Scheuer thank you very much for the deep answer.I have a few notes: 1).when you used the walfram alfa to expand the dominant singularity, how did this work? (Since i tried to check this but did not get this).2) youve substituted a=−1/2 in the theory, but is this correct? Sincd the theory is given for non-zero integer numbers? 3).

Comment: @user726608: You're welcome! :-) Ad. 1.) Try: Series[1/√(1-(3-2√2)x),{x,3-2√2,5}], which gives you the first terms of the expansion at $3-2\sqrt{2}$. Ad. 2.) We can take values $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$ which are *all* complex values, but *not* the non-negative integers. See also Figure VI.5 at page 388 of the referred book by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

Comment: I already checked it, i meant the relation between coefficient of $f(x)$ and coefficient of $f(x_1x)$..that you concluded based on the theorem

Comment: @user726608: We consider $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$.  It follows: $[x^n]f(x_1x)=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx_1^kx^k=a_nx_1^n=x_1^n a_n=x_1^n[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k=x_1^n[x^n]f(x)$.

Comment: @user726608: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)

Comment: @user726608: Interesting problem. I will take a look at it. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Part (b)
$$[x^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x + x^2}} = [x^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt + x^2}}\big|_{t=3}= [x^n]\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(3) x^n $$
where the generating function of the Legendre polynomials has been used.  The exact answer is thus $P_n(3).$  Look up the asymptotics for the Legendre polynomials and you'll find

$$ P_n(t) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}} \frac{ (t+\sqrt{t^2-1})^{n+1/2} }{(t^2-1)^{1/4}}$$ when $t$ is large (outside the oscillatory region.)  Putting in $t=3$ and comparing the asymptotic formula to the exact, we find that, for $n=50,$ the asymptotic formula exceeds the actual by only 0.23%.

The instinct for paying attention to where the singularities are, at $3\pm\sqrt{8},$ (there's a typo in some of your problem setup) is a good one. The penultimate equation utilizes the largest root.  Making this approach rigorous is often called 'singularity analysis.'  I've had Legendre polynomials on the brain for a while, so I didn't want to reinvent a well-known result (I think the above equation can be found in Bender and Orszag.)  Ultimately, an integral representation for the Legendre polynomials is analyzed using the well-known saddle-point technique.

Comment: Thanks, I actually wrote $ 2\sqrt2$ instead of 8 . can I ask how did you find the asymptotic of Legendre polynomial, and what did you mean by comparing jt to the exact one? @skbmoore

Comment: @user726608 The exact answer is $P_n(3).$ Comparing the asymptotic expansion with $P_n(3)$ is what I referred to.  The asym expansion can be found in Bender and Orszag, 'Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers' formula 5.5.16a.

Comment: Hi @skbmoore I finally found the book, but it was not much helpful to me cuz it does not prove the expansion of the asymptotic well..

Comment: @user726608 The Digital Library of Mathematical Functions, eq. 14.15.13, is the same as the formula I give, but parameterized in terms of $\cosh(x).$  (There is a slight difference: instead of $\sqrt{n},$ DLMF's will have $\sqrt{n+1/2},$ but those are asymptotically the same for $n \to \infty.$)  DLMF has as a reference the book by Olver, which may have a derivation.