# Analyzing the Coefficient of a generating function and its asymptotic

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, generating-functions

The generating function
$\sum_{n\geq 0} D(n) x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}$ is the gf of the Delannoy number.

See last paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number

In this link, they mentioned that the coefficient of this gf  is $D(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} { n+k \choose k}$.

My question is how can this coefficient be calculated/extracted from its gf.And how they conclude that it behaves asymptotically as

${\displaystyle D(n)={\frac {c\,\alpha ^{n}}{\sqrt {n}}}\,(1+O(n^{-1}))}$

where
$\alpha =3+2{\sqrt {2}}\approx 5.828$

and

$c=(4\pi (3{\sqrt {2}}-4))^{-1/2}\approx 0.5727$.

How to calculate/extract $D(n)$ from its gf and how to analyze it asymptotically then?
Is that possible to do that with a direct calculations?

*Edit*
I tried to find the asymptotic of the codfficidnt in the above gf this way:

The gf has two poles: $r_1=3+\sqrt{8}$, $r_2=3-\sqrt{8}$. So the smallest/dominant pole is $r_2=3-\sqrt{8}$.
We can write the gf as:
$A(x)=1/ \sqrt{r_2-x} * 1/ \sqrt{r_1-x}$
Then A(x) behaves as:

$1/ \sqrt {r_1-r_2} * 1/ \sqrt{r_2-x}=
1/ \sqrt {2 * 8^{1/4}} * \sum_{n\geq 0} {-1/2 \choose n} (-1)^n (r_1)^{n+1}x^n$
Here I used the expansion's formula  of $(1+x)^a$ for $a=-1/2$ and $x=-x/r_2$.
So the coefficient behaves asymptotically as:
$1/ \sqrt 2 * 1/ 8^{1/4} * (3+\sqrt 8)^{n+1/2} {-1/2 \choose n} (-1)^n$.

We can simplify it more, by using the asymptotic of ${-1/2 \choose n}$.

Is that approach fine?

Comment: For the asymptotics, see [_generatingfunctionology_](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), chapter 5 section 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the asymptotics we use the Wilf text, Theorem 5.3.1 (page 179)
(Darboux) as  suggested in the comments. We seek the asymptotics of

$$[z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6z+z^2}}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{(z-(3+2\sqrt{2}))(z-(3-2\sqrt{2}))}}
\\ = \frac{1}{(3-2\sqrt{2})^n} (3-2\sqrt{2})^n
[z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{(z-(3+2\sqrt{2}))(z-(3-2\sqrt{2}))}}
\\ = (3+2\sqrt{2})^n
[z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{((3-2\sqrt{2})z-(3+2\sqrt{2}))
((3-2\sqrt{2})z-(3-2\sqrt{2}))}}
\\ = (3+2\sqrt{2})^n
[z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{((17-12\sqrt{2})z-1)
(z-1)}}
\\ = (3+2\sqrt{2})^n
[z^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-(17-12\sqrt{2})z)
(1-z)}}.$$

Now here we have one as the dominant singularity on the circle of
convergence and the theorem  applies, taking the parameter $\beta =
-1/2.$ Expanding the term  containing the subdominant  singularity around
one we get for the first (constant) term

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(17-12\sqrt{2})\times 1}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{12\sqrt{2}-16}}
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}.$$

This gives the asymptotic

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{2}-4}}
(3+2\sqrt{2})^n
{n-1/2\choose n}.}$$

The Wilf text gives $O(n^{-3/2})$ for the error in this approximation,
in sync with Wikipedia.

Wilf quotes on the same page an asymptotic for the remaining binomial
coefficient namely

$${n-\alpha-1\choose n} \sim \frac{n^{-\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}$$

with $\alpha$ not a nonnegative integer. In the present case we have
$\alpha = -1/2$ so we obtain

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$$

This gives the form from the Wikipedia entry which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi(3\sqrt{2}-4)}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
(3+2\sqrt{2})^n.}$$

Comment: Very nice answer. (+1) Btw. I've added *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3945490/the-coefficient-and-asymptotic-in-generating-function/3958930#3958930)* an answer to the asymptotic expansion of the central Delannoy numbers based upon P. Flajolet. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The formula you refer to
$$\frac{\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2 \sqrt{n\pi\left(3 \sqrt{2}-4\right)  } }$$ is an asymptotics.

Let $n=10^k$ and computing the logarithms of these monstrous numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 15.91875383 & 15.90706013 \\
 2 & 173.4147070 & 173.4135332 \\
 3 & 1758.735871 & 1758.735754 \\
 4 & 17622.30914 & 17622.30913 \\
 5 & 176268.4035 & 176268.4035
\end{array}
\right)$$ However, even for small values of $n$, it does not seems too bad
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 3 & 3 \\
 2 & 14 & 13 \\
 3 & 65 & 63 \\
 4 & 330 & 321 \\
 5 & 1723 & 1683 \\
 6 & 9165 & 8989 \\
 7 & 49457 & 48639 \\
 8 & 269637 & 265729 \\
 9 & 1481680 & 1462563 \\
 10 & 8192698 & 8097453
\end{array}
\right)$$

In fact, you could find [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00003233/document) a much better approximation for the central Delannoy numbers

$$\frac{\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n}{2 \sqrt{n\pi\left(3 \sqrt{2}-4\right)  } }\times $$
$$\Bigg[1-\frac{23}{19 \left(8+3 \sqrt{2}\right) n}+\frac{2401}{1024 \left(113+72
   \sqrt{2}\right) n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \Bigg]$$

For $n=10$, this would give $8112585$

**Edit**

In fact, there several definitions and in particular $P_n(3)$ (Legendre polynomials). I suggest that you have look at @Zurab Silagadze's anwer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304693/asymptotic-forms-of-legendre-functions-for-large-degree) (make $x=\cosh ^{-1}(3)$).

Another definition of $D_n$ is
$$D(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} { n+k \choose k}=\, _2F_1(-n,n+1;1;-1)=P_n(3)$$

Have a look [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DelannoyNumber.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if it is possible to compute the coefficient $D(n)$ by its gf and analyze it, by hand?

Comment: By hand ???? What I prefer is $P_n(3)$. If you want something simple (but empirical), I coud do it. Tell me the range.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici They want to know why $\sum_n D(n)x^n=(1-6x+x^2)^{-1/2}$ implies $D(n)=\sum_{k} \binom{n}k\binom{n+k}k$, using generating function methods.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici , Mike Earnest is right, that what I actually try to do, but it seems not trivial, if you have another simple way, I would be happy to see..

Answer (score 3):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}[x^k](1+x)^{n+k}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^0](1+x)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^k\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^0](1+x)^n\left(1+\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^{-1}](1+x)^n(1+2x)^n\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\tag{5}\\
> &=[y^{-1}]\left.\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+2x)\,\frac{1-2x^2}{(1+x)^2(1+2x)^2}}\right|_{x=g(y)}\cdot\frac{1}{y^{n+1}}\tag{6}\\
> &=[y^n]\left.\frac{(1+x)(1+2x)}{1-2x^2}\right|_{x=g(y)}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[y^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6y+y^2}}}\tag{8}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we prepare for the substitution rule which is the essence of this derivation.
- In (6) we use the **substitution rule** (Rule 5, one-dimensional case) from section 1.2.2 of G. P. Egorychev's Classic: *[Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-59)*. Here we have
  \begin{align*}
  f(x)=(1+x)(1+2x)\qquad\qquad y(x)&=\frac{x}{f(x)}=\frac{x}{(1+x)(1+2x)}\tag{9}\\
  y^{\prime}(x)&=\frac{1-2x^2}{(1+x)^2(1+2x)^2}
  \end{align*}
  and apply the *substitution rule*:
  \begin{align*}
  [x^{-1}]f(x)^n\cdot \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}=[y^{-1}]\left.\frac{1}{\left(f(x)\cdot y^{\prime}(x)\right)}\right|_{x=g(y)}\cdot\frac{1}{y^{n+1}}
  \end{align*}
  where $x=g(y)$ is the inverted function given by (9).
- In (7) we do a simplification and apply the rule as we did in (3).
- In (8) we note that with $y(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x)(1+2x)}$ we obtain:
  \begin{align*}
  1-6y+y^2&=1-\frac{6x}{(1+x)(1+2x)}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2(1+2x)^2}\\
  &=\frac{(1+x)^2(1+2x)^2-6x(1+x)(1+2x)+x^2}{(1+x)^2(1+2x)^2}\\
  &=\frac{(2x^2-1)^2}{(1+x)^2(1+2x)^2}\\
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6y+y^2}}&=\frac{(1+x)(1+2x)}{1-2x^2}
  \end{align*}

---

*Notes:*

- Another approach of the asymptotic coefficient expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}$ can be found in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3945490/the-coefficient-and-asymptotic-in-generating-function/3958930#3958930)*.
- A somewhat more demanding application of the *substitution rule* (two-dimensional case) is given in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926409/simplify-binomial-sum/3943040#3943040)*.

Comment: Hi @Markus Scheuer thank you, it is much more complicated than I thought! Do you have any idea of how to analyze the coefficient asymptotically، i did edit my post, trying to use some method..

Comment: @user726608: You're welcome! It might seem complicated, but it is also a powerful technique. I have an idea regarding asymptotic expansion. I will provide an answer tomorrow, if nobody else is posting helpful information. Regards,